# ListView is not visible in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android app development.

this is my xml layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button 
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cancel"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/editall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/editall"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fadingEdge="none"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this I am able to see the buttons but list view is not displaying. can Any body help me please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just replace `wrap_content` in place of `fill_parent` at button linear Layout.

change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button 
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cancel"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/editall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/editall"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fadingEdge="none"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And you may consider putting `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` for the ListView, so that it takes all the remaining space

Answer (score 0):

Change inner Linear Layout's height from fill_parent to wrap_content.

Because giving height fill_parent will cover the whole height of the parent that will hide the listview

Answer (score 0):

Did you also set an `Adapter` for your `ListView` in your `onCreate()`? Nothing will be shown on screen if it's empty, as you've also set a transparent background using `cacheColorHint` and applied `wrap_content` height to it's container.